# Transform union type to conditional type

Tags: typescript

Given the two types

```
type UnionType = X | Y | Z;
type ConditionalType<T> = T extends X ? X : T extends Y ? Y : T extends Z ? Z : never;
```

How can we define a transformation which we can apply to UnionType to obtain ConditionalType?

Any input that does something very similar is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create that exact type as it would require recursive type aliases (possible if you trick the compiler, but not recommended).

If my understanding of your requirements is correct you can achieve the desired results using the `Extract` conditional type. This type will extract all members of a union that extend a given type

```
type ex = Extract <UnionType, X> //will be X or anything that extends Xin UnionType
```